# Please help me with Logic Laws?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I'm stuck on this question in my past exam papers and would love some help.

Using the laws of logic show that:
$\lnot(p \lor q) \lor (\lnot p \land q) \iff \lnot p$

I got as far as $(\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor (\lnot p \land q)$ using DeMorgan's law.

However, I'm not sure what law to use next. Can you please explain which one I should use and explain the process. (I'm familiar with all the laws just lack the ability to apply them properly.)

Comment: Now use [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Rule_of_replacement) to get: $\lnot p \land (q \lor \lnot q)$.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}&(\neg p \land \neg q) \lor (\neg p \land q) \\&\iff \neg p \land ( \neg q \lor q), \text{Distributive} \\
&\iff \neg p \land T \\
&\iff \neg p\end{align}

Comment: Can you please explain how did you move the ¬q from left bracket to the right giving you  (¬q  ∨ q) also how did 2 ¬p became one outside bracket? I know how the distributive law works however I've never done question like this.

Comment: The distributive property is used:  Recall, $(\color{blue}{\lnot p}\land \lnot q) \lor (\color{blue}{\lnot p} \land q) \iff \color{blue}{\lnot p} \land (\lnot q \lor q)$